# How can I fix: "start-stop-daemon: warning: this system is not able to track process names" when starting springboot as a systemd service?

Tags: spring-boot, systemd

When I start my spring boot app as a systemd service I receive this error:

`start-stop-daemon: warning: this system is not able to track process names longer than 15 characters, please use --exec instead of --name.`

Spring boot seems to build the process name from the jar name and the directory the jar is contained in.  Is there any way to fix this aside from renaming the jar, and the directory it's contained in, to be shorter than 15 characters?

If I try to edit spring boots startup script to use --exec instead of --name then I get another error:

`'start-stop-daemon: unable to stat /opt/program/programname_optprogramname (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this issue is fixed in Spring boot 2.0.2.  So if you run into this issue upgrading might fix it (not to imply that upgrading is always a simple effort)